# How to add test data for my [Facts] in unit test

Tags: c#, xunit

I am using XUnit framework and I have my unit test case written which is basically creating database and its objects. Now I have to write a test case where I have to insert data in Database. and I am able to do that successfully in below code.

But I would like to know how can I create a set of data which I can use for each of my test case and I don't have to do it again and again. I know there is a way using TabularFixture something in Xunit but haven't used it till today and don't know how it works. So if anyone has any idea?

here is my test case which is inserting data in my db and it works.

```
public class TabularDataFixture
    {
        public TabularDataFixture()
        {
            CreateDefaultLoggerFactory();
        }
    }


    [CollectionDefinition("Tabulardata collection")]
    public class CosmosDbData
    {

[Fact]
        public async Task AddDataInCosmosDbEmulator()
        {
            await ReadConfigAsync();
            Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( DatabaseId, RecordingCollection );
            var jObject = new JObject { { "Data", "Test" } };
            Document doc = await client.CreateDocumentAsync( collectionUri, jObject );
            var response = client.CreateDocumentQuery( collectionUri, "select * from c WHERE c.Data = 'Test'" ).ToList();
            Assert.True( response.Count() > 0) ;            

        }
    }
```

Comment: See Theory, InlineData ,ClassData, TheoryData, MemberData, etc. Good blog posts [here](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) and [here](https://andrewlock.net/creating-strongly-typed-xunit-theory-test-data-with-theorydata/)

Comment: so in this i am adding my each test case as Theory instead of Facts. How can I do it with Fixtures if any idea on that??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "do it with fixtures"